# Zabbix API PHP trigger.get by application-name

Tags: php, api, triggers, zabbix

I'm using Zabbix PHP API and I have a question -

Can I find  triggers by application-name instead of applicationids?
For example:

```
$triggersData = $api->triggerGet(array(
        'output' => 'extend',
        'hostids' => "$hostid",
        'applicationids' => '744',
        'application' => 'CPU',
        'sortfield' => 'priority',
        'sortorder' => 'DESC',
        'active' => '1',    
    ));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, same as everywhere else, you have to first get the entity ID in a separate API call, then use the found ID[s].